# my phone is stolen and sim cards removed. how to track it?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, lost-phone, micromax-a110

my android phone got stolen a few hours ago. the thief has already removed both the internet sims. 
as such, i had not installed AndroidLost or Mobile Tracker apps in the phone as it is a relatively new one. 
i have tried to remotely install it, but it may take time . 
please help out with the procedure and suggest methods to get it back.

Comment: do you have the IMEI number of the phone? It maybe mentioned on the reciept of your purchase.If you got it you can give it to the police to track and they will be able to find it

Comment: or from the link that @Sid suggested, you can try the plan B from the play store and use that.

Comment: Keep in mind that any solution mentioned here and in the linked question only works as long as the device has not been factory-reset (so your Google Account would be disconnected fro the device). After that, the device can only be identified via its IMEI (and a clever thief even could manipulate that).

Comment: thanks a lot people... gonna try all ways out of this. will update whether i get it back or not ..

Answer (score 1):

There can be many other options instead of those apps.

#### Android Device Manager

http://www.android.com/devicemanager

This is the only thing to do, and check where the theif had been for a few last moments. But this isn't perfect.

#### Android IMEI

If you ever wondered what your phone's IMEI is, you would have checked it via *#06# too. If you have it, then go to the government officials who can handle it (I am sorry I cannot guide you to the perfect organisation for that, because I never tried using IMEI to track a phone) and they will help you either in protecting your data or will even get you to your mobile too.

Comment: Good points. Unfortunately the *Android Device Manager* is very far from being perfect. I've tried it with four devices, it worked with none of them (could not locate the device, could not ring it, nothing).

Comment: Yup you're right, my mother just took my phone I tried to track it and it gave me a location just 2 streets away while my mom was more than 400miles away :D But lets wait for it untill its out of beta thing :)

Comment: I doubt it will ever be. For my devices it couldn't find *any* location at all. And if you take a look at Google Cloud Backup, which was introduced somewhere with Android 2.x more than 2 years ago: it's still a "game of fortune" whether restore works at all or at least partially, even with 4.x devices. So no, I wouldn't trust it before having verified it works with the device I intend to use it on. But *if* that's verified, it's a good solution.

Comment: Whether restore would work? You can bet on it! :/ It doesn't work, and it won't work for 4.3 either! You can be sure for this. And yeah, Android Device manager just gets the last location which was sent to Google Maps and shows it. But their ringing thing is awesome :) It rings the phone just in few seconds! :) I love that..:)